# Swift get Coordinates Latitude Longitude in a Variable

Tags: swift, delegates, segue, core-location

I am a newbie and would be thankful for any help.

I want the latitude and longitude Value for my Poststring. 
But it shows that my response string is empty
I want in the below long code in the line:

```
let postString = "latiTude=23&longiTude=12";
```

Put the Users Position. Now I have to put latiTude and longiTude manually,
but I want replace it with the actual users location. I have no Idea how.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


protocol FeedmodelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class Feedmodel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedmodelProtocol!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager() // create Location Manager object
    var latitude : Double?
    var longitude : Double?

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        // set the value of lat and long
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude

    }

    func downloadItems() {
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        // You will need to update your .plist file to request the authorization
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://example.com/stock_service4.php");
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var postString = ""
        if let lat = latitude, let long = longitude {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            postString = "lati=\(Int(lat))&longi=\(Int(long))"
            // do task here now that postString is not empty
        }
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in


            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return

            }


            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")


        }

        task.resume()

    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray;
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {
            print(jsonResult)
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary


            let stock = Stockmodel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if  let Datum = jsonElement["Datum"] as? String,
                let Tankstelle = jsonElement["Tankstelle"] as? String,
                let Kraftstoff1 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff1"] as? String,
                let Preis1 = jsonElement["Preis1"] as? String,
                let Kraftstoff2 = jsonElement["Kraftstoff2"] as? String,
                let Preis2 = jsonElement["Preis2"] as? String,
                let Notiz = jsonElement["Notiz"] as? String,
                let longitude = jsonElement["longitude"] as? String,
                let latitude = jsonElement["latitude"] as? String



            {
                print (Datum)
                print(Tankstelle)
                print(Kraftstoff1)
                print(Preis1)
                print(Kraftstoff2)
                print(Preis2)
                print(Notiz)
                print(longitude)
                print(latitude)
                stock.Datum = Datum
                stock.Tankstelle = Tankstelle
                stock.Kraftstoff1 = Kraftstoff1
                stock.Preis1 = Preis1
                stock.Kraftstoff2 = Kraftstoff2
                stock.Preis2 = Preis2
                stock.Notiz = Notiz
                stock.longitude = longitude
                stock.latitude = latitude


            }

            stocks.add(stock)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

        })
    }
}
```

And this is my php mysql file:

```
<?php



// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("......,......,......,.......");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$firstName= $_REQUEST['latiTude'];
$lastName = $_REQUEST['longiTude'];// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array($latiTude,$longiTude);


// Send back request in JSON format

// Select all of our stocks from table 'stock_tracker'
$sql ="SELECT m. *


      , ( ACOS( COS( RADIANS( $latiTude) ) 
              * COS( RADIANS( m.latitude ) )
              * COS( RADIANS( m.longitude ) - RADIANS( $longiTude) )
              + SIN( RADIANS($Latitude) )
              * SIN( RADIANS( m.Latitude) )
          )
        * 6371
        ) AS distance_in_km

  FROM TankBilliger m
  HAVING distance_in_km <= 100
 ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
 LIMIT 100";

// Confirm there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // We have results, create an array to hold the results
        // and an array to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();



    // Loop through each result
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each result into the results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results


    echo json_encode($resultArray);


}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Are you able to get the user location?

Comment: From where you execute feedmodelInstance.downloadItems() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to import CoreLocation:

```
import CoreLocation
// and add  CLLocationManagerDelegate to the class declaration
```

Then you need to declare the location manager and variables to hold the lat and long values:

```
// set these outside of any functions in your class
let locationManager = CLLocationManager() // create Location Manager object
var latitude : Double?
var longitude : Double?
```

After that is done you want to ask for authorization to use the location of the device. You will need to add the proper items ( `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, and/or `NSLocationWhenInUseDescription` I beleive) to your .plist file to do so.

```
// in the function you want to grab the user's location from
// Ask for Authorisation from the User.
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

// For use in foreground
// You will need to update your .plist file to request the authorization
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Then you'll need to add the function to retrieve the location

```
// Add this function to your program
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    // set the value of lat and long 
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude

}
```

After all of that you will be able to use the latitude and longitude variables whenever you want to. You will also want to tell the `locationManager` to stop updating the location after you get what you want like, `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`.

You can create the string like:

```
// in the function where you need the postString you can do this
var postString = ""
if let lat = latitude, let long = longitude {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() 
    postString = "latiTude=\(lat)&longiTude=\(long)"
    // do task here now that postString is not empty
}
```